# Being vs Is being

Tags: grammar

Which of the following expressions is correct?

A. 2021 is the 20th year the prize is being awarded.

B. 2021 is the 20th year the prize being awarded.

can the second "is" in the sentence be omitted? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's needed. A simpler, rearranged version of the sentence might be "The prize *is* being awarded this year." That becomes "This is the year the prize *is* being awarded."

You could leave out "is" if you brought in another word: "2021 is the 20th year *of* the prize being awarded."